# Problem Creating Subsite

Tags: sub-site

I created windows authentication Web Application using powershell in sharepoint 2013. Application created successfully and than Created Root site collection successfully too. But while creating subsite i get error "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you". Any idea?

Comment: Are you logging with Site admin collection rights?

Comment: Yes offcourse..

Comment: Are you getting any error in Sharepoint logs?

Answer (score -1):

Did you do the user migration too?
Check this article which shows the additional steps to perform after you have converted the web application

Update:Apologies I forgot to post the link!
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/change-sharepoint-authentication-from-classic-mode-to-claims-based

Specifically: perform user migration

$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName

$wa.MigrateUsers($true)